# So my math question is about polynomial congruence $x^2 ≡ 1 \pmod p$ where $p$ is an odd prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $x^2 ≡ 1 \pmod p$ where p is an "odd prime" then what could be the possible values of X for which the congruence is true?

When I looked up on the net it showed that x could be either +1 or -1 but when I plugged in values such as x = p+1 or p-1 ,the congruence is also true but the proof of this congruence tells that there are "only two possible" solutions. I am unable to recognise where the problem is so please help me!

Comment: Please use MathJax formatting when you post in this site.

Comment: Remember that two integers are the same modulo $p$ if their difference is divisible by $p$

Comment: "at most two" $\rm\color{#c00}{unequal}$ roots in $\Bbb Z_p$ means "at most two" $\rm\color{#c00}{incongruent}$ roots $\!\bmod p.\,$ Note that  $\,p\pm 1\equiv \pm1 \pmod{p}\,$ so they do not yield more than two roots $\!\bmod p.\ \ $

Comment: $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field. Any polynomial has at most two roots. You can check that $1,-1$ are two roots and that they are distinct, since $p$ is odd. So, there are precisely two roots *modulo $p$*

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as $x^2 -1 ≡0$ mod $p$. So $(x+1)(x-1) ≡0$ mod p. So $p | (x+1)(x-1)$. Hence, by Euclid's Lemma, $p|x+1$ or $p|x-1$, so $x+1≡0$ mod $p$ or $x-1≡0$ mod $p$. This means $x≡-1$ mod $p$ or $x≡1$ mod $p$ as required. $\square$